# Calling CUDA function from OpenACC with gang parallelism

Tags: cuda, interop, openacc

I am trying to call Zhang's tridiagonal solver code from openacc. 
I do the following:

I put his code in a separate file and compile called pcr.cu

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__device__ void Solve_Kernel_PCR(float * alist, float * blist, float * clist, float * dlist, float * xlist, int iter_max, int DMax)
{

    int idx_row = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row_max = DMax - 1;

   // printf("idx_row = %d iter_max= %d\n",idx_row, iter_max);

    int stride = 1;
    int next_stride = stride;

    float a1, b1, c1, d1;
    float k01, k21, c01, a21, d01, d21;

    bool next_or_ot = true;
    int accum;


 for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_max; iter++)
    {
        if ( next_or_ot ) {

            next_stride = stride<<1;

            // 1    for updating 'a'
            if ((idx_row - stride)<0) {
            // 1.1  if it is the 'first' line
                a1 = 0.0f;
                k01 = 0.0f;
                c01 = 0.0f;
                d01 = 0.0f;
            } else if ((idx_row - next_stride)<0) {
            // 1.2  if no place for 'a'
                a1 = 0.0f;
                k01 = alist[idx_row]/blist[idx_row - stride];
                c01 = clist[idx_row - stride]*k01;
                d01 = dlist[idx_row - stride]*k01;
            } else {
            // 1.3  for rest general rows
                k01 = alist[idx_row]/blist[idx_row - stride];
                a1 = -alist[idx_row - stride]*k01;
                c01 = clist[idx_row - stride]*k01;
                d01 = dlist[idx_row - stride]*k01;
            }

            // 2    for updating 'c'
            if ((idx_row + stride)>row_max) {
            // 2.1  if it is the 'last' line
                c1 = 0.0f;
                k21 = 0.0f;
                a21 = 0.0f;
                d21 = 0.0f;
            } else if ((idx_row + next_stride)>row_max) {
                c1 = 0.0f;
                k21 = clist[idx_row]/blist[idx_row + stride];
                a21 = alist[idx_row + stride]*k21;
                d21 = dlist[idx_row + stride]*k21;
            } else {
                k21 = clist[idx_row]/blist[idx_row + stride];
                c1 = -clist[idx_row + stride]*k21;
                a21 = alist[idx_row + stride]*k21;
                d21 = dlist[idx_row + stride]*k21;
            }
            // 3   for updating 'b'
            b1 = blist[idx_row] - c01 - a21;
            // 4   for updating 'd'
            d1 = dlist[idx_row] - d01 - d21;

            stride = next_stride;

      int pos = idx_row-2*stride;
            accum = 0;
            for ( size_t iter = 0; iter<5; iter++ ) {
                if (pos >=0 && pos < DMax) accum++;
                pos+=stride;
            }
            if (accum < 3) {
                next_or_ot = false;//Turn of for ever
            }

        }

        __syncthreads();

        alist[idx_row] = a1;
        blist[idx_row] = b1;
        clist[idx_row] = c1;
        dlist[idx_row] = d1;

    }

    if ( accum==1 ) {
        xlist[idx_row] = dlist[idx_row] / blist[idx_row];
    } else if ( (idx_row-stride)<0 ) {
        int i = idx_row; int k = idx_row+stride;
        float f = clist[i]/blist[k];
        xlist[i] = (dlist[i]-dlist[k]*f)/(blist[i]-alist[k]*f);
    } else {
        int i = idx_row - stride; int k = idx_row;
        float f = alist[k]/blist[i];
        xlist[k] = (dlist[k]-dlist[i]*f)/(blist[k]-clist[i]*f);
    }

}
```

and the main.cpp file:

```
 #pragma acc routine gang bind("_Z16Solve_Kernel_PCRPfS_S_S_S_ii")
__device__ void Solve_Kernel_PCR(float * alist, float * blist, float * clist, float * dlist, float * xlist, int iter_max, int DMax); 

int main(int argc, char *argsv[]) {

  size_t diagonal_size ;
 diagonal_size=atoi(argsv[1]);


  float *alist = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * diagonal_size);
  float *blist = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * diagonal_size);
  float *clist = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * diagonal_size);
  float *dlist = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * diagonal_size);
  float *xlist = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * diagonal_size);

  float delx=1./(diagonal_size-1);

  for (int i = 0; i < diagonal_size; i++) {
    alist[i] = 1.0f;
    blist[i] = -2.0f;
    clist[i] = 1.0f;
   // dlist[i] = -1.; // rand() % 100 + 1;
    xlist[i] = 0.0f;
  }

  float pi = atan(1.0) * 4.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < diagonal_size; i++) {
    dlist[i] = -pi * pi * sin(OMEGA * i * delx * pi) * delx * delx;
}
 alist[0] = 0.0;
  clist[diagonal_size - 1] = 0.0;
  int DMax = diagonal_size;
  int iter_max=count_iter(DMax);

  printf("iter_max= %d\n", count_iter(DMax) );

  int ngang=1;

  int N=diagonal_size;



 #pragma acc data copy(alist[0:diagonal_size],blist[0:diagonal_size],clist[0:diagonal_size],dlist[0:diagonal_size] ,xlist[0:diagonal_size]  )
    {    
    #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(ngang) 
   Solve_Kernel_PCR(alist, blist, clist,  dlist, xlist, iter_max, DMax);
    }
     for (size_t it = 0; it < diagonal_size; it++) {
        // std::cout << alist[it] << " " << blist[it] << " " << clist[it] << " " <<
        // xlist[it] << " " <<  dlist[it] << std::endl;
        //printf("%f \n", xlist[it]);
        printf("%f \n", dlist[it]);
      }

  float err0 = 0.0;
  float err1 = 0.0;
  for (int i = 1; i < diagonal_size-1; i++) {
    // printf("r %lf %lf %lf %lf\n ",dl[i], d[i],du[i], r[i]);
    err1 = fabs(dlist[i] - sin(OMEGA * i * delx * pi));
    if (err0 < err1) {
      err0 = err1;
    }
  }

  printf(" l infinity of Error = %lf \n",err0 );
}
```

This is a simple test case, as I would like to call this function from within a openacc gang routine.

compiling the cuda code with 
"nvcc -rdc true -arch=sm_60"
and linking with pgc++ it links fine.

However the results are wrong for the input value > 32

I assume this is because of the default vector length of 32. 
I need to be able to handle meshes upto 1023.   Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't gone through this in detail, but you have control over the vector length in OpenACC.  Changing this: `#pragma acc parallel num_gangs(ngang) ` to: `#pragma acc parallel num_gangs(ngang) vector_length(1024)` should do that.

Comment: I tried that before, It does no accept the vector_lengt(1023), it accepts it but igonres while running, for example, when I run with the PGI_ACC_NOTIFY=1, it still prints out  device=0 threadid=1 num_gangs=1 num_workers=1 vector_length=32 grid=1 block=32

Comment: vector_length of 1023 is not legal on NVIDIA GPUs.  It must be a multiple of 32

Comment: The mistake is not as simple as you assume #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(ngang) vector_length(1024) I meant 1024 it is still gets ignored

Comment: Try adding the flag "-ta=tesla:gvmode".  "gvmode" (gang-vector mode) is an undocumented flag which will disable the restriction of using only a vector length of 32 when call device routines.  By default, PGI limits OpenACC routines to a vector length of 32.  This needed in order to support reductions in routines as well as limiting the amount of thread synchronization which hurts performance.  Though since you're device routine is written in CUDA, it should be fine to disable.  Also, be sure to compile with "-Mcuda" in addition to "-ta" to tell the compiler you're linking with CUDA code.

Comment: Thank you so much Mat, indeed it solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the flag `-ta=tesla:gvmode`.

"gvmode" (gang-vector mode) is an undocumented flag which will disable the restriction of using only a vector length of 32 when call device routines. By default, PGI limits OpenACC routines to a vector length of 32. This needed in order to support reductions in routines as well as limiting the amount of thread synchronization which hurts performance.

Though since you're device routine is written in CUDA, it should be fine to disable. Also, be sure to compile with `-Mcuda` in addition to `-ta` to tell the compiler you're linking with CUDA code.

[Answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry for posterity]